# Customize VSCode to use a console emulator instead of the command prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code, conemu

Can I customize VSCode to use a console emulator instead of the command prompt?

I want to use something like conemu, but don't want to use "force conemu as default terminal for console applications" setting in conemu.

It has a specific warning "enabling this option may cause false alarms in antiviral programs", and I'm on my work computer.

Comment: Actually, there were no DefTerm specific false alarm reports yet.

Comment: Also using ConEmu (big thanks for it btw!) at work here with the option to force it as default terminal and it works great so far :)

Comment: Could really use something similar for GNU/Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They have just implemented this feature:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/3495

You'll have the **externalTerminal.windowsExec** and **externalTerminal.linuxExec** user settings, where you can define what console emulator to use.

In my case, I'm on windows using conEmu. My user settings (settings.json) are configured like follows:

```
{
    "externalTerminal.windowsExec": "conEmu64.exe"
}
```

EDIT: It's already available in the stable version.

Comment: Please note that they have changed the setting to "terminal.external.windowsExec"

Comment: This doesn't work properly.  Specifically, it doesn't allow you to pass in command-line parameters to reuse the existing instance or change to a specific working directory.  Thankfully there's a plugin called "ConEmu Launcher" that does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a simple extension that overrides key binding `Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+C` with command `console.open` defined by this extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/vilicvane.console

It's not working with "Open in Command Prompt" context menu item though.

Comment: I read this and your blog post. Just what file do I make the JSON changes to?

Comment: @Hoppe Your user settings. Try `Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+P` and enter "user settings".